# Windows 7 Remote Desktop is disconnecting me

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am logging into a Windows 7 Remote Desktop using my credentials and the machine is automatically logging me off after a minute saying "Your session has expired, another user has logged in using the same credential (etc.)".

I changed my login password and it still does that. I realised that somehow auto-login is enabled and it's logging me off to prevent concurrent sessions. I used a registry fix to solve this problem, but was told off by my administrator not to do that. Is there any work around so that I don't have to fiddle with auto login, but continue with my current session without getting logged off.

KR,

Comment: Ask your administrator how you should be doing it?

Comment: @DavidPostill     That's the problem. Administrator sometimes works from home and doesn't like people "Fiddling" with things. I want a quick workaround

Comment: Send him an email?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get you logged off automatically:

- There may be an Idle-Timeout configured on the server, accidentally set to one minute. Ask the system administrator to check this.
- The Server may also be configured to allow you just login once. If you start your second RDP-session, the first one will be terminated.